# Having an issue relating classes

Tags: c#

I cannot get the two classes to communicate properly. I need to have two classes, otherwise this wouldn't be a problem.

The problem:

> Write a console application that will ask the user to input the wholesale price, then display the mark up percentage prices. You will need to format each line so they can all be displayed on a single command screen.
>   Create a class/object to do the actual work of the calculations (business layer). There is no need for a data class in this exercise. Use an instantiated object for your business layer.

I know that I am missing something, but I am not sure what it is.

What I have:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BusinessClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MarkupClass item1 = new MarkupClass();
            Console.WriteLine("what is the whole sale cost: ");
            item1.wholeSaleCost = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    class MarkupClass
    {
        private decimal markupPercent = 1.05m;
        public decimal wholeSaleCost;
        public decimal DoCalculations(decimal wholeSaleCostIn)
        {
            while (markupPercent < 1.11m)
            {
                decimal finalCost;
                finalCost = wholeSaleCostIn * markupPercent;
                Console.WriteLine("The wholesale price is: {0} and the final selling price is {1}", wholeSaleCostIn, finalCost);
                markupPercent = markupPercent += 0.01m;
            }
            return markupPercent;
        }
    }
}
```

If this was just one class it would be easy, but the question requires two classes.

Comment: It's really unclear what your problem is - you created a second class with a method but aren't even calling that method. What is your question?

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm sorry, this is our first look at classes and I'm not entirely sure what the issue i. I simply do not understand how to make the classes work with each other

Comment: What part of this school assignment did you do yourself till now? Don't forget to call `item1.DoCalculations( item1.wholeSaleCost )` Your markupPercent statement looks a bit fishy. The method you call, will return a value, eventually  (probably `1.11m`)

Comment: @Icepickle I typed everything that is up there. What looks weird about the markupPercent

Comment: @UnholySheep I figured it out, I am ultra new to this. Like you said, I made the method but never called it. I was thinking the issue was with my classes, but that wasn't the problem. Sorry, probably could have figured that one out more if I had thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read and understand more about object oriented programming basics

For time being try executing and understanding this program. I have done changes that you were expecting.I have not modified much, but this should work to begin with.

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BusinessClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MarkupClass item1 = new MarkupClass();
            Console.WriteLine("what is the whole sale cost: ");
            decimal wholeSaleCost = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            decimal markupPercent = item1.DoCalculations(wholeSaleCost);
            Console.WriteLine("Final % is :  {0}",markupPercent);    
        }
    }
    class MarkupClass
    {
        private decimal markupPercent = 1.05m;
        public decimal wholeSaleCost;
        public decimal DoCalculations(decimal wholeSaleCostIn)
        {
            while (markupPercent < 1.11m)
            {
                decimal finalCost;
                finalCost = wholeSaleCostIn * markupPercent;
                Console.WriteLine("The wholesale price is: {0} and the final selling price is {1}", wholeSaleCostIn, finalCost);
                markupPercent  += 0.01m;
            }
            return markupPercent;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped, like I said above I am ultra new to this. I realized that in my original code I never called the method from the second class that I made. I thought the issue was with my classes, but that wasn't quite it. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you suppose to call `DoCalculations` function to perform calculation

```
       MarkupClass item1 = new MarkupClass();
       Console.WriteLine("what is the whole sale cost: ");
       string input =  Console.ReadLine(); //getting value in string format
       decimal input_decimal  = Decimal.Parse(input); // caste string input into decimal 
        item1.wholeSaleCost = item1.DoCalculations(input_decimal); // pass it to DoCalculations to do calculation
```